# Procedure for developing on top of feature branch when original feature branch is merged with a squash

Tags: git

It's not that uncommon when I find myself:

- needing to work on the next feature
- before the latest work is integrated to the main branch
- and new work requires code from the previous branch
- and the merge into main is a squash.

When this happens, merging is painful.

The scenario:

```
git checkout develop
git checkout -b feature/A

git commit -am "A1" 
git commit -am "A2" 

git push // + start a pull request

//Before the pull request is finished 

git checkout -b feature/B
git commit -am "B1" 

// Pull request is accepted and merged as a squash

// Other pull requests 

git fetch origin develop
git merge origin/develop
(conflicts)
```

Now:

- `feature/B` has `A1`, `A2`, `B1`
- and `develop` has a commit `D1` that has the changes from `A1` and `A2`
- and git cannot know that `D1` is `A1`+`A2`
- and it rightly marks places where `feature/B` touches code changed by `feature/A` as
  conflicts.

Ideally I would love to be able to:

1. not have conflicts where what's coming in from `develop` to `feature/B` came from `feature/A` and
2. have conflicts if the change came from another branch (or not from commits `A1` and `A2`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So You have

feature A:

```
O---A1---A2
```

feature B:

```
O---A1---A2--B1
```

Then the squash is done on the upstream, you need to fetch the update:

```
git fetch
```

```
O---A1---A2--B1 <--featureB
 \
  \--D1 <-- origin/develop
```

You try to merge,

```
O---A1---A2---B1--XX Conflict
 \               /
  \--D1---------/
```

You need to rebase B1 on D1, not a merge

```
git rebase --onto origin/develop featureA featureB
```

will do

```
O---A1---A2
 \         
  \--D1--B1
```

Comment: @TTT thanks I did the update