# Github: creating a feature branch from another branch that is in review

Tags: git, branch

I'm not very familiar with github, but I have a situation where branch A added some changes and is now under review in a PR to merge to master. I'm working on a new feature that needs changes from branch A and so I created a branch B based on branch A. When I make a PR for branch B to be merged to master (which will be merged after A is squash merged I believe) how do I make it so that it only has the new commits to B. Also, I can't directly make changes to master, everything has to go through a pull request and reviews.

I tried understanding how rebase works but I still don't quite get it.

[image: Branch Diagram]

Comment: If i use rebase --onto does that replace the need for a pull request to master?

Comment: If you don't squash, there is nothing to do

Comment: I think it will be a squash and merge for branch A

Comment: so I am detailed what to do on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71350023/procedure-for-developing-on-top-of-feature-branch-when-original-feature-branch-i